# Should I install airflow inside a Docker or inside a virtual enviromment?

Tags: docker, airflow, virtualenv

I'm a linux user for more than 10 year and have been learning to use airflow from **some tutorials**.

But I have made such a big mess on my OS, to the point I could not even stop airflow from startup on boot. I could not run any dag that I have made, could not uninstall it. Could not even use it in a virtual enviromment, because there was another airflow on port 8080 (as I said, I did a lot of tutorials). So on...

So I decided to make a clean linux reinstall and start from scratch. And I want some roadmap to not make those mistakes again.

I have some experience in virtual eviromment from using with python. I know the basics of Docker.

I'm confused about should the airflow run inside a docker? Or the docker runs inside the airflow?

If I run airflow outside docker, should the airflow (with all the pip packages) be installed inside a virtual enviromment?

What should I learn before airflow?

What would be the roadmap to run a simple Bash and Python Operaror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the docker compose solution. Airflow as docker container (worker and scheduler).

Follow the instructuons from airflow [official page.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html)

Another option is to use Astronomer solution for airflow that wrappes airflow deploy with thier cli tool and many video guides.